# Cannot convert value of type 'Response<AnyObject, NSError>' to closure result type 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift, exception, response

```
class AlamofireService {


static let alamofireService = AlamofireService()


private init() {

}

internal func makePostServiceRequest(url: String, parameters: AnyObject, completion: (inner: () throws -> NSDictionary) -> Void) -> Void{


    Alamofire.request(.POST, URL_BASE, parameters: [IOS_PARAMS : parameters], encoding:.JSON).validate()
        .responseJSON

        {
            response in switch response.result
            {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")


                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                print(response)

                completion(inner: { return response })



            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                completion(inner: { throw error })

            }
    }
}



internal func makeGetServiceRequestTemplates(completion: (inner: () throws -> NSDictionary) -> Void) ->Void {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, URl_TEMPLATES).validate().responseJSON

        {
            response in switch response.result
            {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")



                if let array = JSON as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

                    for var i=0; i < array.count; i++ {

                        let templates = Mapper<VQuizTemplateTo>().map(array[i])
                        print(templates)

                    }


                }
                completion(inner: { return response }) //error is on this line


            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                completion(inner: { throw error })
            }

    }
}
```

Two identical methods, for the first there is no errors and for the second is on place as i marked. Can't figure out what is wrong, especially with this non sense error.
Could you tell me what i'm doing such wrong?

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` you are returning is of type`Response<AnyObject, NSError>`, which is why you are getting that error..

Try returning this instead `response.result.value as! NSDictionary`

Just  replace `completion(inner: { return response })` with

`completion(inner: { return response.result.value as! NSDictionary })`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! There is no errors in the first Alamofire request, still don't get it how is that possible, but it's important that this works

Comment: There is no error in the request, but you are trying to assign value of type `Response<AnyObject, NSError>` to a `NSDictionary` which is the reason for the error you were getting.